# How do I stop a lot of elements overflowing from a parent div's boundry

Tags: html, css

So I'm trying to make a type speed test. It displays random words and makes you type it. It works, it can display text and when I type it shows if I typed it correctly. I accomplished this by making each character a separate element:

```html
<section class="container">
        <char>a</char>
        <char>b</char>
        <char>c</char>
</section>
```

The whole css file:

```css
:root {
    --bg-color: #0A122A;
    --font-untyped: #7E7F9A;
    --font-correct: #29E7CD;
    --font-wrong: #E65F5C;
    --font-size: 24px;
}

html body {
    color: var(--font-untyped);
    background-color: var(--bg-color);
    font-size: var(--font-size);
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.wrong {
    color: var(--font-wrong);
}

.correct {
    color: var(--font-correct);
}

.current {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    height: auto;
    word-wrap: break-
}
```

When there are too much characters, it overflows. It just gets cut from my screen.
I tried:

```css
overflow-wrap: break-word;
word-wrap: break-word;
overflow-x: hidden;
height: auto;
width: auto;
```

But none of these work.
What I want to accomplish is that it goes to the next line, instead of going off screen.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: There's something else in you CSS class that is making the chars run in a single line. "display: flex;" for example. Post the rest of the code.

Comment: @luenib Okay, I'll add the code.

Comment: Dorji Tshering is right. If your container is displayed as a flex, you then need to set flex-wrap: wrap; in order for the chars to jump to the next line when they run out of space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the property `flex-wrap: wrap` on the `.container` class because the default value is `nowrap` which doesn't allow the flex items(each character in our case) to continue on the new line. If each container is a new word, and you have a container wrapping those containers, then the `flex-wrap: wrap` should be applied on that too. Let me know if it works.